# Agregar sidemenu con ionic 2

Tags: ionic

Hola tengo un proyecto en desarrollo con ionic. Y necesito mostrar un sidemenu, pero los ejemplos que he conseguido son utilizando el template sidemenu de ionic el cual funciona muy distinto. 
Si podría explicarme o colocar un link para ver como podría hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es simple, crea un nuevo componente en la vista (*HTML*) y agrega lo siguiente:

```html
 <ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item>
        Opcion 1
      </button>
      <button menuClose ion-item>
        Opcion 2
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Y esto en el archivo *".ts"*:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'menu.html',
})
export class MenuPage {

  public rootPage: any;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.rootPage = HomePage;
  }

}
```

Para utilizarlo en otro componente solo tendrás que agregar un botón con la propiedad `menuToggle` de esta manera:

```
<button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon </button>
```

Comment: el ion-menu va dentro del header?

Comment: No, el ion-menu va primero y cierra al final del ion-content

Comment: ok. gracias por la ayuda.